# My wallet rpc server's balance doesn't update

Tags: mining-pools, transaction-unlock-time

Pool admin here, I have the money, and I've waited 30 blocks and it says its not unlocked yet along with the rpc server not updating its balance. Should I just wait or is something wrong.

```
2016-11-10 08:53:54 Error with transfer RPC request to wallet daemon {"code":-4,"message":"not enough money"}
2016-11-10 08:53:54 Payments failed to send to {"amount":100000000000,"address":"x"} { amount: 200000000000,
  address: 'x' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Waiting 10 more mins until it reached ~60 block maturity allowed me to access my coins. The problem wasn't to do with the server, but to do with the fact that the mined coins must wait much longer than normal transactions before they can be unlocked and spent.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1130)

Comment: @ferretinjapan It does, I should have just waited. I tried using funds that were not unlocked, plus I am the author

Comment: @ferretinjapan you can still revise your answer to make the context clear for readers so they can understand and benefit from it..

Comment: @UsernameFV It would have been better if your answer contained a little more detail as it's very brief and rather vague, but it's all good, at least you were able to get your coins :).

Comment: Yeah, its a little weird tho, since it was about 60 and now its taking over 70

Comment: I believe it is 60 blocks until coinbase matures, which will be approximately 120 minutes, but of course there will be variance.